# regarding [ThreadStatic()] c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the meaning of [ThreadStatic()]

i got a piece of code and i found `[ThreadStatic()]`
is used there what does it mean....when to use `[ThreadStatic()]`

```
public class Context
{
[ThreadStatic()]
private static Context _Context = null;

private HttpContext _HttpContext = null;

public Context()
{
    _HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
}

public static Context Current
{
    if(_Context == null || 
       _HttpContext != _HttpContext.Current)
    {
        _Context = new Context();
    }
    return _Context;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx):

> Indicates that the value of a static field is unique for each thread.

In your code `_Context` is static, but it is different for each thread.

If you have a background in more native programming, think of these as a semi-equivalent of Thread Local Storage.

Comment: I don't think the points about asp.net are entirely accurate.  A thread can be reused between requests so storing per request data in thread local isn't 100% safe.  There are easier and safer ways of storing information per request.

Comment: @James - Thanks - you are correct, threads are re-used; but 1 thread is never handling more than one request at a time since it just draws them from the thread pool. I removed the sentence to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx):

> Indicates that the value of a static field is unique for each thread.

Read these:

- [A tale of two techniques: The [ThreadStatic] Attribute and System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx)
- [CallContext vs ThreadStatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273301/callcontext-vs-threadstatic)
- [MSDN Blog: Are you familiar with [ThreadStatic]?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/07/18/670497.aspx)
- [How well do you understand ThreadStatic?](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/01/09/code-quiz-how-well-do-you-understand-threadstatic.aspx)