# Is it safe to cache StringBuilder with [ThreadStaticAttribute] when asynchronous code used?

Tags: c#, .net

There is a pattern that allows to cache [StringBuilder] instance per thread, using the [ThreadStaticAttribute]. I wonder if it's safe to cache when asynchronous code is used. I mean after the async part is completed, the continuation may start in another thread and the cached [StringBuilder] will be corrupted

Comment: It's often a good idea to also share the code in front of which you are thinking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010688/613130 The response of Marc Gravell was to not play with `ThreadStatic` and `async`

Comment: you should not use `ThreadStaticAttribute` in async context, use [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-5.0) at least.

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool has special detection for string builder/custom cached pool. You might consider using that rather than building your own. It's designed for aspnet.core but you can use it anywhere. It's async safe, mainly because it's up to you to return the object to the pool/cache