# Can I rely on CallContext using Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Can CallContext be relied upon, through-out the whole request, when using asp.net Web API?

I have read the [decade-old blog post](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) and I'm not sure it still applies (as asked [there](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html?showComment=1399390806034#c4998076937967713504)).

Assuming Thread-Agility kicks in, if I set data in a global filter, is it safe to assume it will be there through-out the request?

Comment: I have tested with CallContext.LogicalSetData and async controller (to make it switch threads before and after) and it seems to work fine. However that's quite a complex subject and it's hard to be sure by just performing simple tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lose your CallContext if ASP.Net switches threads. In an asynchronous model, the asp.net task scheduler will take care of joining async calls back to a request thread *with the same HttpContext*, but not necessarily the same thread.

Example: A request starts and then you go off to asynchronously wait for some slow IO before returning - while you're waiting for that slow IO there's no reason for your request thread to be sitting around doing nothing so it may get used for another request.

ASP.Net is a big exercise in `Thread Agility` (google it), and there is also a great discussion about this here: [CallContext vs ThreadStatic vs HttpContext](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?572-CallContext-vs-ThreadStatic-vs-HttpContext&highlight=LogicalThreadContext)

Comment: CallContext.LogicalSetData and .LogicalGetData is supposed to work for async.

Comment: @imukai `CallContext` was designed for remoting, and you're right - it should work for async, but on who's word? It was designed before Async even existed. It isn't documented anywhere that I could find; the only info I have is from reading other threads of people discussing and nobody seems to agree on the behaviour of `CallContext` inside asp.net. It's much better to use an `AsyncLocal` as it was designed for this purpose and *is* documented.

Comment: `You lose your CallContext if ASP.Net switches threads.` Is this correct? I am also looking at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273301/callcontext-vs-threadstatic

Comment: @themefield: A quote from the question you linked: `Very often a request will use the same thread throughout, but it certainly won't always be the case`. This means that very often your CallContext might be the same one, but it might not always be. Check out `AsyncLocal` for an async safe way to store thread specific data.

Comment: @caesay I think the sentence `Very often a request will use the same thread throughout, but it certainly won't always be the case` is saying that very often the thread might be the same one, not that the `CallContext` might be the same one.

Comment: @themefield If I remember, the thread is the same, the CallContext will be the same - if the thread has been changed, the CallContext will be new. Although, you could test yourself to verify if this is important to you!